# convert-video library has no exports

Tags: angular

i've deploy an app in angular 12 using the convert-video library ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-video ) but when i run the command ng serve it fail to compile my application 'cause convert-video has no exports

error :

./src/app/shared/components/media-uploader/media-uploader.component.ts:340:48-70 - Error: export 'VideoConverter' (imported as 'VideoConverter') was not found in 'convert-video' (module has no exports)

this is the index.js of the library:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNkjv.png)